# How to replicate a matlab model for copula (copulafit) in python

Tags: python, matlab, distribution, resampling

I have found this simple very well-explained example of copula which is absolutely fine for my purpose.
https://it.mathworks.com/help/stats/copulafit.html

I would simply need to replicate it.

However, I cannot use Matlab but Python.
Do you know how I can replicate what's in here in python?
For example, I have tried Copulas, but for some reason I cannot visualise the copula but directly the multivariate distribution of my resampled data

Answer (score 0):

In python you can use Copulas library (https://sdv.dev/Copulas/index.html)

Comment: yes as mentioned I have already tried but something seems to be missing like a visualisation of the copula itself in the plane [0,1], an estimation of the quality of fitting like the -log-likelihood and possibility of choosing among different types of copulas for example t-copula..maybe it is my fault that i cannot find these features, so if you know how to estimate these things with Copulas, pls let me know

Comment: You mean by visualization the representation of the copula with scatter_2d(df)? For fitting I would use scipy.stats (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/stats.html).

Comment: thanks for replying. Yes i mean that but after fitting and resample if I do a scatter, it plots the multivariate distribution resampled not the underlying copula used to generate that multivariate. I would like to see both. How would you use the scipy fit after the copula creation? will I be able to then have the goodness of fit, in order to compare different choices of univariate distribution (gaussian, gaussianKDE etc.)?